# Peer to Peer communication with Cordova on a local network

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on a Phonegap application and I want a means by which two people with this app installed can share some information **offline**, but on the *same network like a wifi or tethered hotspot*.

I have tried to search the web for possible libraries or ways of doing it, but all I see are libraries that pass the data through their servers before sending it to the peer, meaning they must be online.

So please can someone point me to the right direction on how to do this or to the valid resources available. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you have found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [sockets-for-cordova](https://github.com/blocshop/sockets-for-cordova) for communicating between a cordova app and an Arduino. However, seeing as it's TCP it wouldn't support broadcasts - you'll need a UDP socket for that.

There is also [cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp)  which does appear to support broadcasts. I've no experience with it though.